React error boundary shows wrong line numbers in stack trace
The error below is thrown on line 13 of App.tsx, but the stack trace says line 35. How can I get the React error boundary to show line numbers corresponding to my actual files, instead of these transpiled ones?

App.tsx
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Inner />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
}

function Inner() {
  throw new Error("Error: I crashed!");
  return "App";
}

export default App;

ErrorBoundary.tsx
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
interface State {
  error: any;
  errorInfo: any;
}

const defaultState: State = {
  error: null,
  errorInfo: null,
};

// https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html
// https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = defaultState;
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: { componentStack: string }) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error
    console.log("ErrorBoundary", { error, errorInfo });
    console.log(error instanceof Error);
    this.setState({
      error: error,
      errorInfo: errorInfo,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const fallback = (
      <div>
        <section>
          <h3>An error occured.</h3>
          <h4>error.message</h4>
          <pre>{this.state?.error?.message}</pre>
          <h4>error.stack</h4>
          <pre>{this.state?.error?.stack}</pre>
          <h4>errorInfo.componentStack</h4>
          <pre>{this.state?.errorInfo?.componentStack}</pre>
        </section>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState(defaultState);
          }}
        >
          Try again
        </button>
      </div>
    );

    if (this.state?.error?.message) {
      return fallback;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;

The first two messages in the console show the correct line number (13) which indicates source maps are working, but the third one shows 35 and that's what is shown in the ErrorBoundary.

My project was created using by npm create vite and looks like this:


is thrown on line 13 - are you sure? line 35 looks like it throws "Error: I crashed" - the error you are seeing

@JaromandaX It's in line 35 of the bundled/transpiled code at http://localhost:5173/src/App.tsx:35:9, but in the original code that is on line 13. I also notice that 3 different console messages appear for one error, the first two with the correct line number and the 3rd one with the incorrect one which is what appears in the ErrorBoundary. https://imgur.com/a/dpddLol

yes, and what does the browser run? that's the line the error is reported on

Check if you can activate "source maps". I don't know about vite, but in next.js this is activated by default, and would display the line in the original source code in error messages.

The first two error messages shown in the console for my screenshot have the proper stack trace, so that seems to indicate that source maps are enabled and working. It's just the third one that differs, and that's the one I get in the ErrorBoundary. I've edited the images from my last link into the original post
